# In linq to sql can I have a select (and groupby) within a groupby?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following classes:

```
class XXX
{
    int XXXType{get;set;}
    List<YYY> Children{get;set;}
}
class YYY
{
    int YYYType{get;set;}
}
```

I want to find the number of items with the same value for the property XXXType and for each of these groups I want to find the number of items whose children have the same value for the property YYYType. Does linq to sql support a select/group within a select/group? I don't get any compile/runtime exceptions but the length of YYYChildren is always zero.

```
(from x in XXX).GroupBy(x=>x.XXXType, (key, values) => new {
    XXXType = key,
    Count = values.Count(),
    YYYChildren = (from y in values.SelectMany(z=>z.Children).GroupBy(y=>y.YYYType, (key, values) =>
        new {
             YYYType = key,
             Count = values.Count()
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

//sample data

```
   var xxxList = new List<XXX> {
            new XXX()
            {
                XXXType = 1,
                Children = new List<YYY>() {
                        new YYY() {YYYType = 1},
                        new YYY() {YYYType = 1},
                        new YYY() {YYYType = 2},
                        new YYY() {YYYType = 2}
                    }
            }
        };
```

//Query :

```
        foreach(var x in xxxList.GroupBy(info => info.XXXType)
                    .Select(group => new { 
                         key = group.Key, 
                         Count = group.Count(),
                         YYYChildren = (from y in xxxList.SelectMany(z=>z.Children).GroupBy(y=>y.YYYType, (key, values) =>
                                        new {
                                             YYYType = key,
                                             Count = values.Count()
                                        }) select y.YYYType)
                    }))
        {
             Console.WriteLine("XXXType :{0}, Number Of XXXTypes :{1}, Number Of YYYChildren :{2}", x.key, x.Count, x.YYYChildren.Count());
        }
```

Result :
XXXType :1, Number Of XXXTypes :1, Number Of YYYChildren :2